# openlayers 4 method forEachLayerAtPixel() throws SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: openlayers, security

Working with GeoExt 3.1.0, ExtJS 6.2.0 and Open Layers 4.4.1.

I am trying to select a layer on my map with the **singleclick** event so I can use **layer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl** and display the information contained in the table row corresponding to the selected/clicked geometry on the layer (just like the **layer preview** option given by GeoServer in **OpenLayers** format). So far:

```
                map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
                    document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";
                    var view = map.getView();
                    var viewResolution = view.getResolution();

                    var pixel = evt.pixel;
                    //pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent); <-- tried with and without this line
                    map.forEachLayerAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(layer) {
                        var source = layer.getSource();
                        console.log(layer);
                        return true;
                    });
                    var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
                            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
                            {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50});
                    if (url) {
                        document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
                    }
                });
```

Problem:

The method **forEachLayerAtPixel** is causing this error `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` to appear in the firebug console every time I click any point on the map (on or off any geometry)
[image: Security Error: the operation is insecure]

I have read articles relating this problem to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` tag being missing, AFAIK this is resolved (in my case in GeoServer Jetty) by adding this chunk of code:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

in:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\jetty\etc\webdefault.xml`

and including this `{mode: 'cors'}` along with the url being targeted in the **AJAX** call. At least this is how it is working for me.

Or maybe this has nothing to do with the problem, in which case this question just got a lot longer then it should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is too easy to be true and maybe it will crack somewhere in the future but for the time being:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    name: 'name',
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'geoportal:layer'},
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous' //<-- THIS IS THE SOLUTION
    })
})
```